# How to open Options page from content script when button click CHROME EXTENSION?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to open my extension's options page when I click button in content.js.

I tried this, but does not opens options.html.

can someone help me please?
thanks in advance

manifest.json

```
"options_page": "options.html",
```

options.html

```
   <p>hello world</p>
```

content.js

```
let btt = document.querySelector('.settings-icon-hk');
btt.addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.open('../options.html')
  
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't open the options page directly from `content.js`. Your browser will display an error message. Instead, you need to send a message to the background script and tell it to open the options page:

content.js:

```
let btt = document.querySelector(".settings-icon-hk");
btt.addEventListener("click", () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("showOptions");
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  if (request === "showOptions") {
    [...]
  }
});
```

Nevertheless, if you try to open the `options.html` file using  `window.open('../options.html')` the browser will try to open the file on the server where it most probably doesn't exist. You have to tell the browser to open the `options.html` file of the extension:
`window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL('options.html'));`

You have to tell the browser that it should open the option.html file of the extension:

`window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL('options.html'));`

Actually you don't need to take this detour and use a function provided by Chrome itself:

```
chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
```

This function has the advantage that it recognizes the "`open_in_tab`" setting of `manifest.json`.

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  if (request === "showOptions") {
    chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
  }
});
```

You find this and more information about the option page at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options